# C# Get MSMQ Messages in System Queues

Tags: c#, msmq

So C# allows me to use GetPrivateQueues and GetPublicQueues but there is nothing to get System Queues.  I have written this code

```
string deadLetterQueuePath = @"formatname:DIRECT=OS:.\system$;DeadLetter";

MessageQueue deadLetterQueue = new MessageQueue(deadLetterQueuePath);

Message[] messages = deadLetterQueue.GetAllMessages();

foreach (Message message in messages)
{
    Console.WriteLine(message.ToString());
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The code fails on the MessageQueue line.  Here is the error I get

"The specified format name does not support the requested operation. For example, a direct queue format name cannot be deleted."

Could this just be a limitation of running this against my Windows 8 PC?  Am I doing something wrong?  Could this be a permission issue since the account I am using is not a local admin even when I can pull private and public queues?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something I answered in the old MSMQ newsgroups a while ago might help if it's a permissions problem.

[No Manual or Programmatic Access to Dead Letter or Any System Queue](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/microsoft.public.msmq.programming/manual/microsoft.public.msmq.programming/-tFfWyFhWXM/wAj7lN_PowoJ)

Comment: Interesting.  Even as an admin on my local PC, it would not work.  I never thought to check the object in AD.  Thank you for this information.

Answer (score 0):

So the code above is good. Just doesn't work against my Windows 8 box. Works fine on one of my MQ Server 2012 servers.

Comment: Won't be OS-dependent.